# C - Returning negative value as unsigned sets errno?

Tags: c, unsigned, errno

Good day,

I'm reading through some old code I've been asked to maintain, and I see a number of functions that are like so:

```
uint32_t myFunc(int* pI);
```

In the case of error conditions within the body of the function, the function exits early by returning a negative `errno` value, ie: `return (-EINVAL);`

Is this value standard (ie: C99, ANSI), C? I've read in the comments that apparently doing this sets the `errno` to `EINVAL`, but I can't find any documentation to support this. Wouldn't it be better to just declare the function as a signed int (ie: `int32_t myFunc(int* pI)`) and treat negative values as error codes, rather than attempt to set `errno` in this manner?

Comment: I don't think any error will be returned anyway... I think your negative integer will be converted to unsigned (The same binary representation of the negative integer will be used for the unsigned you assign the value)

Comment: i think so. use positive number this place is weird. as least it go against linux convention.

Comment: Is this kernel code?

Comment: For this _interesting_ function, certainly `myFunc()` returns values 0 ... 0xFFFFFFFF-4096 are "normal" return values and 0xFFFFFFFF-4096+1 ...  0xFFFFFFFF are "error values.

Comment: @KeithThompson No, it is not kernel code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning a negative value **does not** set `errno`. This is misinformation you picked up (or more likely, which the original author picked up) out-of-context: the mechanism by which the *Linux kernel system calls* report errors is returning a negative value in the range -4095 to -1, which the userspace code making the syscall then uses (in most cases) to fill in the value of `errno`. If you want to set `errno` yourself, however, just assign a value to it.

Answer (score 2):

Addressing your question: *Is this value standard (ie: C99, ANSI), C?*

For C99

```
    "errno which expands to a modifiable lvalue that has type int, the
    value of which is set to a positive error number by several library
    functions." -- N1256 7.5p2
```

For POSIX

```
    "The <errno.h> header shall define the following macros which shall
    expand to integer constant expressions with type int, distinct
    positive values" -- errno.h DSCRIPTION

    "Values for errno are now required to be distinct positive values
    rather than non-zero values. This change is for alignment with the
    ISO/IEC 9899:1999 standard." -- errno.h CHANGE HISTORY Issue 6
```

A good discussion (and the source of these quotes) is found ***[HERE](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.unix.programmer/Len9F7Hrqyw)***  (search "when to return EINVAL")